# Olimex ARM-USB-OCD-H with LPC-P1114 and LPC-P1227 boards questions

Tags: arm, development-tools

I'm having a big headache with ARM-USB-OCD-H with LPC-P1114 and LPC-P1227 Olimex boards.

After reading the Manual IAR I figured out that I need to configure my OpenOCD Server to use the ARM-USB-OCD-H programmer with my targets.

The configuration file for the ARM-USB-OCD-H are provided but there are no targets for LPC-P1114 or LPC-P1227 in TCL folder or board configuration files.
I tried to download the new OpenOCD version 0.7.0 but this version also doesn't have config files for these targets.

First question: ARM-USB-OCD-H is able to program and debug these NXP LPC targets?
Second question: Where can I get configuration files for these targets?

Comment: You might need to make one by finding a similar existing configuration, comparing the relevant part of the chip data sheets, and making corresponding changes to the files.  In terms of something existing, I'd think mailing lists related to the project would be a better place to look than here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is that you cannot program these processors using the ARM-USB-OCD-H, at least not with OpenOCD. The important point is that the LPC11xx processors require a Single-Wire Debug (SWD) interface rather than JTAG, and I suspect that the LPC12xx have the same requirement. Olimex sells an SWD adapter for the ARM-USB-OCD-H but the web site indicates that is only works with Rowley Crossworks.

You might look at using an LPC-Link. You can cut an LPCXpresso board in half and use the programmer separately from the target, and I think there is support for using it with gdb.

Comment: Thank you @Joe. I bought an JLink from Segger and all my problems are now solved!